# rails models relation - looking for the simplest code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

Beginner question:

An activity can have multiple participants. Each activity have a date, but you can have different activities the same day. A join table make the link between the participants and the activities.

I'm looking for the simplest way to list all the participants of the day. Also I'm trying to make a simple "count" to know how many participants where there on a single date.

```
Activity.last.participants.count
```

Give me the number of my participant for this single activity

```
Activity.where(avtivity_date: Date.today)
```

Give me an array with all the activities of the day. So i have to iterate through each of them to count or list the participants and make a sum.

I'm looking for something like:

```
Activity.where(avtivity_date: Date.today).participants.count
```

To return the number of the participants for the day.
Is this possible? Should i continue to iterate and count ?

I not sure of the keywords i can use to make a documentation search, any tips/docs links will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join of the two tables

```
Activity.where(activity_date: Date.today).joins(:participants).count
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `select` and `group` clauses to select all the participants in that day. Then use the `.count`:

```
Activity.where(activity_date: Date.today).select(:participant_id).group(:participant_id).count
```

Comment: Not as efficient, but also works with `.uniq` instead of `.group(:participant_id)`